# Unused arguments of sarima()

Tags: r, arima

When I am trying to run

```
sarima(log(AirPassengers),0,1,1,0,1,1,12)
```

It returns

> Error in sarima(log(AirPassengers), 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 12) : 
>     unused arguments (1, 1, 12)

The dataset is under the package of `astsa` package. The data type is `ts` type.

```
class(AirPassengers)
[1] "ts"
```

I don't know the reason of this error. I ran the same code in DataCamp, it works.

Answer (score 1):

A few general comments:

1. You can fit SARIMA models with base R's `arima` function; there is really no need to load an additional package for fitting basic SARIMA models.
2. The `AirPassengers` dataset is part of base R, not part of `astsa`.

In `arima`, you specify the non-seasonal and seasonal parameters through function arguments `order` and `seasonal`, respectively. You can find detailed information what arguments the function takes if you type `?arima` into an R terminal.

For example, to specify a SARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,1)<sub>12</sub> model you do

```r
arima(log(AirPassengers), order = c(0,1,1), seasonal = list(order = c(0,1,1), period = 12))
```

Note that the `seasonal` argument is a `list` with the two elements `order` (denoting the order of seasonal AR terms, order of seasonal differencing, and order of seasonal MA terms) and `period`.

---

The error you're seeing with `astsa::sarima` seems to stem from too many arguments; check that you really have 3 non-seasonal arguments, 3 (optional) seasonal arguments, and one (optional) period.

Above model would be

```r
sarima(log(AirPassengers), 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 12)
```

which produces the same fit results as `arima` (in fact `sarima` just calls `arima` "under the hood").

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Very helpful!

Comment: @Candice2020 If this answers your question, please close the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy and make it easier for future readers to identify relevant questions. It also gives a small reputation award to both the poster and answerer, which is the standard way of saying "thank you" around here. Cheers.